# How do you make an embedded flash player open the little window telling them to update it?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

The flash player has a little window that can be opened (similar to flash->settings) telling the user to update the player if the movie loaded is for a more recent version. How can you instruct the player to do this? ITV have managed it with their catchup-tv player.

Context: I am allowing users to copy flash into their PowerPoint presentations and would like to tell them to update their flash player if necessary. I am not embedding a web page in the power point so no JS can be run for checking etc (because I know this is not necessary).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For getting the current version of flash:

```
var version:String = Capabilities.version;
```

I don't know what ITV has done, but I don't know of any way of forcing the player to show that box, although it may do it automatically.

EDIT:

I just found a complete [blog post](http://www.negush.net/blog/get-flash-player-version-with-as3/) that answers this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will be useful. I just decompiled the ITV player but haven't spotted how they did it.

Comment: I think it's probably handled with php or javascript that you can't see. Or that you can see. Or maybe flash itself automatically checks to see whether the swf is a higher version

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force the window to open itself. It's a [user defined](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager05.html) setting: [image]

Comment: That is not the one James is after, I believe. It is this one, but I don't know how to open it and make it do its thing outside of a web page and without JavaScript involved: http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject/_jcr_content/articlecontentAdobe/image_5.adimg.mw.215.jpg/1276140875726.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Security](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#showSettings%28%29) class.  I have used it in some Flash to prompt users to increase storage limits.  The panels that you can show are found in [SecurityPanel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/SecurityPanel.html).  However, this may not be the way to prompt for outdated Flash version.  (If you are looking to *customize* these panels, that is off limits.)

You can actually test the browser/Flash version in Javascript, so there really is no point in loading Flash to tell the user to upgrade Flash.